# postgresql: логарифмическая сложность при формировании хэш-индексов

Tags: postgresql, производительность, хеширование, индексация, индексы

построил в Postgresql для столбца, содержащего отдельные слова хэш-индекс:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_dbg_hash_topic ON dbg_t USING HASH (topic);
```

проверил на размном кол-ве строк и оказалась, что имеется логарифмическая зависимость

[image: зависимость времени (в сек) формирования индекса от кол-во строк]

Учитывая, что у меня рабочая таблица имеет 40М+ записей, то формироваться индекс будет 10 суток.

**Почему так происходит, откуда логарифмическая зависимость? И можно ли формировать индекс быстрее?**

Сами хэши считаются быстро, откуда такое падение производительности не понятно.

Comment: насколько равномерное распределение данных? Топ-100 самых частых значений какую часть таблицы покрывает? Самый худший случай для hash - большинство строк имеют одно и то же значение.

Comment: да, одно значение в 4,5 раза встречается чаще, чем все остальные вместе взятые (остальные распределены с ростом где-то в 1,5 раза относительно предыдущего) , но как это влияет?

Comment: одинаковые значения гарантированно попадают в один bucket, а там с множеством TID не происходит ничего сильно хорошего. Это известная слабая сторона hash индекса. hash в postgresql применим для около уникальных данных, при том достаточно длинных. Иначе btree будет и быстрее и даже компактнее.

Comment: да, проверил - для задачи получить кол-во уникальных слов в столбце (слова от 5 до 15 символов) получилось, что индекс btree дает в 10 раз большую производительность, чем hash и как я понимаю быстрее уже ничего не сделать (никакой другой индекс), разве что если словарь слов сильно ограничен, то заменить слова числами